# i have trouble installing the pyautogui module on python

Tags: python, windows

whenever i  use the `pip install pyautogui` command i get this error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Hello\python scripts> pip install pyautogui  
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.53.tar.gz (59 kB)
  ERROR: Error [WinError 5] Access is denied while executing command python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
Check the permissions.
```

Answer (score 0):

in my experience `Access is denied Check the permissions` is error because you don't have permissions to add or edit file in your `C:/` Folder. In Windows, you have to `run as administrator` to do adding and modifying file.

try this `pip install pyautogui --user`

`--user` flag is equivalent to run as administrator